# how can i always show the bar of the scrollbar even if the content is not too big to fit

Tags: html, css, sass, less

The overflow property specifies whether to clip the content or to add scrollbars when the content of an element is too big to fit in the specified area.

i'm asking if there is any way to always show the scroll bar even if the content of an element is not too big to fit.

below here i added an image, what i'm looking for is to show the bar.

[image]

Comment: `overflow: scroll` would work for you =) and here you can see the options https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: @halilcackar thx . I'm still need a scenario when I got the bar showing .

Comment: In CSS the only way is `overflow: scroll`. I don't really what you mean by showing bar. You can show the complete element but if there is nothing to scroll, you can't show the scroll bar element that move.